# How to deploy ASP.NET website project with MSBuild

Tags: .net-3.5, msbuild, asp.net-3.5

I am trying to create a batch file to build a solution that contains mutilple projects and a ASP.NET website project. Output should be a "build" folder containing result of ASP.NET website precompilation.

Using below approach, all projects are getting compiled and build folder is getting created for individual projects under each directory. And for website, new folder "precompiled" is created with all required dll's and .aspx files.

But I need ASP.NET website files to be placed in one single 'build' folder and compilation for rest of C# libraries must be done in individual BIN folders.

```
<Target Name="Build">
     <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)" Condition="!Exists('$(OutputPath)')" />
     <MSBuild Projects="@(Solution)" Properties="OutputPath=\Build"/>
</Target>

<PropertyGroup>   
     <OutputPath>Build\</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I've read for compiling website projects, 'aspnet_compiler' task must be used. But it is not compiling project dependencies, resulting in reference errors. After I compile the projects individually and it works fine.

Inshort, it should be inplace MSBuild for C# projects and asp.net project should compile into seperate 'build' folder. Any insights appreciated.